# In .net core 3x, Regex Match, Groups cannot be input to Enumerable extensions

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

Please Consider this code:

```cs
var regEx = new Regex("sample");
var match = regEx.Match("Some sample text");
var a = match.Groups.Skip(1).First().Name;
```

This will compile and work under 2.2 but compile error in 3.1:

```
error CS1061: 'GroupCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Skip' and no accessible extension method 'Skip' accepting a first argument of type 'GroupCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Interestingly, changing it to:

```cs
var regEx = new Regex("sample");
var match = regEx.Match("Some sample text"); 
IEnumerable<Group> groups = match.Groups;
var a = groups.Skip(1).First().Name;
```

will fix the error.

Why is this error hapening, and what breaking changes has caused this?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/41445 ?

Comment: Did you try using Values of Groups like:
 match.Groups.Values.Skip(1).First().Name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to this change here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/30077

As per discussion, if was not even considered to be a breaking change, do it wasn't mentioned in any changelog as such:

> If it was caught in preview we probably would have reverted it; but given that we've already shipped an LTS version with the change it's probably there forever now.
>
> Somewhat ironically, we were talking about an overload ambiguity problem from IEnumerable and IReadOnlyDictonary in an API Review today, but we apparently missed this as an ambiguity on extension method invocation because this now has two different IEnumerables.

Suggestions include using cast to get a typed `Enumerable`

```
 int matches = m.Groups.Cast<Group>().Count(t => t.Success);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because 'GroupCollection' doesn't have extension method for 'skip' in Linq and so you need to cast it to 'IEnumerable' to use 'skip' extension method of Linq.

The 2nd method you wrote, You would be casting it to IEnumerable or calling ToList() to make it 'IEnumerable'.